# Rails - mixin module - check if base responds to a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mixins

I have created a module in order to implement a common controller action: `order`

When I define the method I want to check if the controller that has included the module, responds to a specific method (`authorize_respond`).

How can I achieve that?

Find below my current implementation **that doesn't work** (never calls the method `authorize_ordering`).

```
def order
  send(:authorize_ordering) if self.respond_to?(:authorize_ordering)        
  ordering = params[:ordering]
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassing, never mind.

Method `authorize_ordering` was protected. Being public works as expected.